# Django Rest Framework HyperLinkedRelatedField: allow id instead of url for POSTS requests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to allow a HyperLinkRelatedField to accept just an id instead of requiring a hyperlink to create a new instance of an object, but for get requests I would like to return the hyperlink not just an id but it appears to be either one or the other. Is this possible?

```py
class Blog(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('url', 'id')

class Comment(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    blog = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='blog-detail', queryset=Blog.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('url', 'text', 'blog')
```

**GET** Request for Comment returns (This is perfect):

```
{'url': 'mysite.fake/comments/1', 'text': 'test text', 'blog': 'mysite.fake/blog/1'}
```

**POST** Request requires:

```
{'text': 'test text', 'blog': 'mysite.fake/blog/1'}
```

I want to also be able to pass:

```
{'text': 'test text', 'blog': '1'}
```

Comment: You can use `serializers.ModelSerializer` instead of `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and I'm not sure if there is a corresponding `serializers.RelatedField`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible but not out of the box.

You should use a `ModelSerializer` and define your own relational field.
Start with a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and override the `to_representation` so it returns an [url instead of an id](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L354).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a `blog_id` field and explicitly set it to an instance of `serializers.IntegerField`. e.g.

```
class Comment(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    blog = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='blog-detail',
queryset=Blog.objects.all())
    blog_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('url', 'text', 'blog', 'blog_id')
```